# How to I convert a list containing strings of tuples to a list of tuples?

Tags: tuples, python-3.7

I have a list of string tuples that look like this

```
['(-315.0, 106.0)\n', '(-179.0, -163.0)\n', '(90.0, 76.0)']
```

How would I go about converting that to this

```
[(-315.0, 106.0), (-179.0, -163.0), (90.0, 76.0)]
```

I have tried `eval()` in my code that didn't change the list at all. That code was

```
        with open("{}.ctd".format(load), "r") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            positions = []
            for i in range(len(data)):
                data[i].rstrip()
                print(eval(data[i]))
                positions.append(data[i])
            print(positions)
            draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = ['(-315.0, 106.0)\n', '(-179.0, -163.0)\n', '(90.0, 76.0)']    
res = [ast.literal_eval(d) for d in s]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['(-315.0, 106.0)\n', '(-179.0, -163.0)\n', '(90.0, 76.0)\n']
result = []


for item in data:
    exec('result.append({})'.format(item), {'result':result})
print(result)
```

**Or**

```
for item in data:
    result.append(eval(item))
print(result)
```

**Output**

[(-315.0, 106.0), (-179.0, -163.0), (90.0, 76.0)]

Answer (score 0):

Python code to convert list of tuples into list

```
# List of tuple initialization 
lt = [(-315.0, 106.0), (-179.0, -163.0), (90.0, 76.0)] 

# using list comprehension 
out = [item for t in lt for item in t] 

# printing output 
print(out)
```